# How to invoke Java method and access properties from embedded groovy without a prefix

Tags: java, groovy

I am embedding Groovy into a Java application with GroovyScriptEngine.  I put all the relevant properties into the binding and all works fine.  For completeness, here is a snippet:

```
public class GE2 {
    GroovyScriptEngine gse;
    Binding binding;

    public GE2() throws Exception {
        this.gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(new String[]{"scripts"});
        binding = new Binding() {

            @Override
            public Object getProperty(String property) {
                // this method is never called when trying println name2 from groovy
                return "Prop: " + property;
            }

        };
        binding.setVariable("GE2", this);
        gse.run("t1.groovy", binding);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "theName";
    }

    public void doIt(String... args) {
        System.out.printf("Doing it with %s\n", Arrays.toString(args));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new GE2();
    }
}
```

My groovy script t1.groovy is as below:

```
println GE2.name // this correctly prints theName
// println name2 <- this raises No such property: name2 for class: t1
GE2.doIt('a', 1, 42); // this works as expected too
```

Is there a way I can 'bypass' the `GE2.` and use GE2 **properties and methods** directly from the script?

I am using JDK 7, and Groovy 2.1

Answer (score 2):

[`CompilerConfiguration`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration.html) enables you to set a `scriptBaseClass`, from which stuff will be invoked. Can you use [`GroovyShell`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html)? There seems to be [some caveats](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/setScriptBaseClass-does-not-work-for-GroovyScriptEngine-td5710646.html) with `GroovyScriptEngine` and `CompilerConfiguration` (though they are probably solved/workaroundable):

File `Shell.groovy`:

```
def script = '''
  println GE3.name // this now prints the GE3's class name
  println name 
  doIt 'a', '1', '42'
'''


def config = new org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration(scriptBaseClass: GE3.class.name)
def binding = new Binding()


new GroovyShell(binding, config).evaluate script
```

File `GE3.groovy`:

```
abstract class GE3 extends Script {
  String getName() { "John Doe" }

  void doIt(String... args) {
    System.out.printf("Doing it with %s\n", Arrays.toString(args));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement all the members yourself and link them

```
public void doIt(String... args) {
    GE2.doIt(args);
}
```

thus calling them from your own class.

Comment: But then I will have to do all of these methods and properties again in groovy.  I'd like my groovy to not have any extra boilerplate stuff like this.

Comment: If you want to bypass the static GE2 call, you will have to put something between it. There is no other way to do it in Java. The only way to omit the `GE2.` part is to make the callable method a method of the class you are working on.